# Running Mathematica in the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud, webservices

Which solutions are available in order to run a Mathematica notebook or package in the cloud? I would like to have access to at least say 30 cores.
I found the following two options:

1. [Wolfram Private Cloud](https://www.wolfram.com/private-cloud/) whose price starts at $25,000 (and so it is not an option for me).
2. [Mathematica on Amazon Cloud](https://www.nimbisservices.com/shop/product/mathematica-on-amazon-cloud-licensing-service/) by Nimbis which has a price 1.5 times the Amazon EC2 one.

Did you guys try one of these (or other) solutions? In case, how is the work flow? Suggestions?

Comment: I must say I have a side question on running Mathematica (kernel) on an AWS EC2 instance (not Nimbis): does Mma license management act gracefully with this, or does it see a restarted image being a new machine, requiring a license transfer?

Comment: Because there is no running a real front-end in AWS,lots of functionality is severely restricted.

Answer (score 5):

As Mitch suggested, I asked WRI support:

Q: Can I run Mathematica Enterprise on a virtual machine on AWS, so I can use all of the licensed cores? What are the other available options for running my copy of Mathematica Enterprise on a cloud service, so I can use all of the licensed cores?

A: "Well, not sure.  I’ve asked the question to the people who make these kinds of decisions and expect to hear back soon.  The issue is a License Agreement issue where it states the installation must happen on a machine owned by the individual.  At a minimum, this kind of language needs to be cleaned up before me saying yes with a 100% confidence."

Answer (score 1):

How one sets this up really matters r.e.cost, and is driven by your data needs, computation needs, and UI needs.  From a business view it's worth the time to plan your requiments and know your budget.  One can quickly spend more on AWS than the cost of a physical machine, but then one must maintain the machine.  It's the age old question, should I buy or should I rent?

Comment: Do you have any updated advice about running Mathematica in the cloud to access more cores?

Comment: Best place to start is contacting the Mathematica cloud sales folks.  Explain your requirements and situation and see what they say.

Comment: Thanks, I have sent them an email about it.